# Node - Middleware req.param nested json parse issue

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, parsing, nested

Im not sure if Im passing back a properly formed JSON array to do what I want.  My attempts to parse it are failing so I thought I would ask here.

```
{"email":"myemail@email.com","teamname":"Team1","team":"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"}
```

I can't seem to JSON.stringify(req.params.team)

```
undefined
```

For JSON.Stringify(req.params.team[0]) I get

```
undefined
```

Or sometimes i get

```
 "["
```

I can see the data in the DOM before it sent back.  It looks good.  Have i sent back a ill formed param or is there some way I can break down this JSON data as is for the team stuff so I can insert into my database properly?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Been a long weekend, would like to get this insert done if possible.  Thanks!

******SOLVED******

I forgot to use my body parser and wasn't sending a post through.  I switched my fetch get to a fetch post (im using REACT in the front end).  Here's what worked.  Thanks @Avi

```
      fetch(`/team/`,{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: this.context.user.email,
    teamName: this.state.value,
    team: this.state.selected,
  })
})
```

And my middleware (simplified) just so I can see what im getting.

```
app.post('/eventerteam/', function (req, res) {
console.log("MIDDLE::SUBMIT EVENT TEAM CALLED::email "+ (req.body.email)); 
console.log("MIDDLE::SUBMIT EVENT TEAM CALLED::teamName "+ (req.body.teamName)); 
console.log("MIDDLE::SUBMIT EVENT TEAM CALLED::team "+ JSON.stringify(req.body.team));    
 })
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do ? Get a JSON object from the request or send a JSON object to the response ?

Comment: Im going to need to parse this "team" stuff to do a proper insert in my database.  So right now im just trying to poke around in it, see how I can traverse it before I make my DB insert essentially.

Comment: Im getting a JSON object from the request.

Comment: Do you use the express framework ?

Comment: Yes Im using Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you send a POST request with `Content-type: application/json`
you should be using `body-parser` middleware to extract the JSON object from the request as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/teams', function(req, res){
 var teamsObject = req.body;
});
```

Comment: yes, body parser!  I forgot.  Give me a minute.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: So that all works.  Thanks for the help.  I'll update my question with the answer as well.  Much appreciated.